# React DevExtreme React Grid Filtered Rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, devextreme, react-grid-layout

I've been using DevExtreme React Grid for the past few days and am having a little bit of trouble with the documentation.

I implemented the search bar feature using SearchState, SearchPanel, and IntegratedFiltering like the documentation says to do. My question is whether it is possible to return the list of rows displayed by the table after the filtering happens.

Each row on the table represents a website and whenever the row is displayed, I want it to ping the website to check if the website is up. With pagination, I can find which rows I need to ping by finding which page I'm currently on and how many rows there are per page. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the search bar implementation. Any help would be appreciated.